# How to use atomic directive into sections in openmp

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

i am parallelizing two loops using section directive of openMP.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section    //section 1
    {
       
        for (conditions){
            statement
    } }
    #pragma omp section    //section 2
    {
     #pragma omp for
     for (conditions){
            statement
      } }
}
```

The reason is both two loops are independent of each other. The first loop has dependent statements so it can not be parallelized and its execution time is large whereas the second loop can be parallelized. But if I apply parallel directives only on the second loop then it has to wait for its execution until the first one is completed.

So I am trying to execute both loops in parallel using a section or task where in the first section first loop can be executed sequentially and in the second section the second one can be parallelized.

I don't know whether it will speed up the program or not. But before getting any results, I was stuck on how to run the first loop in the section sequentially.

Comment: The "*apply atomic directive on the first section for that loop so that the first loop can execute sequentially*" make no sense to me and is very unclear. I do not think you want to perform atomic operations but maybe critical section. Please provide a minimal working example (in sequential) or explain much more precisely the actual problem. By the way, sections are not much used anymore now. They have now mostly been super-seeded by tasks that are much more flexible (tough not a complete replacement).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark On your suggestion, I edited the post to elaborate more on the problem.

Comment: "how to run the first loop in the section sequentially" Your code already does that. One thread does the first section, and it runs the loop sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use tasks to achieve your goal (to run 2 loops simultaneously: one of them sequentially and the other in parallel):

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    #pragma omp task    
    for (conditions){
        //serial loop
    }
    
    #pragma omp taskloop
    for (conditions){
        //parallel loop
    }        
}
```

Note that your question has nothing to do with atomic operations.